# framework 7 onclick event div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-framework-7

1. i add toolbar at main view.for some reason i enable to paste code at StackOverflow code section.

look at image

[image]

2.onclick event at toolbar works with `<a>` tag but not work with `<div>` tag.

```
<a onclick="playButton()" class="link size-50" id="play"><i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

above code work fine.

```
       <div id="myProgress" onclick="alert(11)">
            <div id="myBar"></div>
         </div>
```

on same page on click at div tag not working

Comment: You need to make sure your `div#myProgress` has a width and a height

Comment: it has width and height 

#myProgress {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}
#myBar {
    width: 1%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}

Comment: Move the `height` property to `#myProgress`

Comment: still ...not working bro..

Comment: Provide the CSS you are using and the HTML. Maybe create a jsfiddle?

Comment: parent <div> clickable, <a> clickable but normal div not clickable .. any suggestions ?

Comment: It's hard to know without the bigger picture. It works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/itodd/u9rx6srq/

Comment: yes i also run at jsfiddle. check this link https://framework7.io/docs/toolbar.html  only <a> tag mention

Comment: i tried with normal div like <div  id="myProgress" onclick="alert(11)">some text </div>..it also work.. what d F.. not work with        <div id="myProgress" onclick="alert(11)">
            <div id="myBar"></div>
         </div>

Comment: Are you able to copy all of your CSS here?

Comment: when i put any <div> tag inside <div class="toolbar-inner"></div> onclick event working but color of div not shown or not properly align

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165160/framework-7-on-click-event-work-at-div-class-toolbar-inner-div-but-not-ou
look at this question

Comment: hi bro.. i solve this problem